# Using Shiny to create multiple plots, one of which requires parameters estimated using the data

Tags: r, shiny

I am clearly relative new to R-Shiny and I am getting something done... Right now I am running in a bit of a problem that I do not seem to be able to overcome.

I am reading data for some stock, computing the returns and I would like to do two plots: one of the returns and one of the histogram (density like) + the plot of the estimated normal and skewed normal.
The code works outside of Shiny and it is not even difficult at all, really.

I also checked and my Shiny interface works as well. Plot 1 works.. If I replaced the part related to plot 2 with the same code for plot 1, I get the two plots. The problem is that something, somewhere, in creating the second plot fails. I am using functions and maximum likelihood estimates.  I keep getting error messages along the lines of *"operation not allowed without an active reactive context"* . I modified almost everything I could, but 2 days later, nothing seems to work  Is there anyone who could help me ? Please...

Here is the code I am using:

```
    library(tidyquant)
    library(timetk)
    library(moments)
    library(stats4)
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    
    stocknames <-c("AAPL","TSLA", "GME", "GOOG", "AMGN")
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Fitting a skewed normal to stock returns"),
      
      sidebarLayout(position="left",
                    sidebarPanel("Choose a stock from the list",
                                 selectInput("tick", label = "", choices=stocknames)
                    ),
                    mainPanel("main panel", fluidRow(
                      splitLayout(style="border:1px solid silver:", cellWidths = c(400,400),
                      plotOutput("plot1"),
                      plotOutput("plot2")
                      )
                    )
      )
    )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      stockDatax <- reactive({
             tq_get(input$tick, get="stock.prices", from ="2015-01-01")
      })
             daily_returns <- reactive({
               stockDatax() %>%
                tq_transmute(select = adjusted,           # this specifies which column to select   
                mutate_fun = periodReturn,   # This specifies what to do with that column
                period = "daily")     
        
      })
      
                          
             plt1 <- reactive({daily_returns() %>%
               ggplot(aes(x = date, y = daily.returns )) +
               geom_line() +
               theme_classic() +
               labs(x = "Date", y = "daily returns") +
               ggtitle(paste("Daily Returns for ", input$tick)) +
               scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years", date_labels = "%Y") +
               scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.5,0.6,0.05),
                                  labels = scales::percent) 
                      
             })
#  This is where the part related to plot 2 begins and where the error(s) lie...
             
             x<- reactive({pull(daily_returns,2)})
             n <- reactive({length(x()) })
# need this function for log-likelihood function immediately below.
             csi0 <-function(x){
               y<- log(2*dnorm(x))
               return(y)
             }
             
    # define likelihood function for skewed normal         
             ll<-function(mu, sigma, alpha){
               n()*log(sigma)+ sum((x()-mu)^2/sigma^2) - sum(csi0(alpha*(x()-mu)/sigma)) # negative log-likelihood
             }
# This uses mle to find the mle solutions numerically.             
             est<-mle(minuslogl=ll, start=list(mu=0, sigma=1, alpha=-0.1))
             summary(est)
# extract the solutions to use them individually in what follows             
             m <- reactive({ unname(est@coef[1]) })
             s <- reactive({ unname(est@coef[2]) })
             a <- reactive({ unname(est@coef[3]) })
#
# symbolic probability density function that uses the parameters just estimated above.             
             dsknorm <- function(x){
               y <- 2/s*dnorm((x-m())/s())*pnorm(a()*(x-m())/s())
               return(y)
             }
# doing the same for the normal distribution.             
             # MLE for normal distribution
             m1 <- reactive({mean(x()) })
             s1 <- reactive({sd(x()) })
             
             dnorms <- function(x){
               y <- dnorm(x, m1(), s1())
               return(y)
             }
             
             grid_x <- reactive({ seq(min(x())-.03, max(x())+0.03, .005) })
             ylistskdf <-reactive({sapply(grid_x(), dsknorm)})
            ylistnormdf <-reactive({sapply(grid_x(), dnorms)})

# create a dataframe to use for plotting
             dataToPlot <- reactive({data.frame(grid_x(), ylistnormdf(), ylistskdf()) })
        plt2 <- reactive({ggplot(data=dataToPlot(), aes(x=grid_x())) +
           geom_line(aes(y=ylistskdf(),colour="skewed_normal")) +
           geom_line(aes(y=ylistnormdf(),colour="normal")) +
           scale_color_manual(name="distribution", values=c(skewed_normal="blue", normal="red")) +
          daily_returns() %>%
           ggplot(aes(x = daily.returns)) +geom_density()+
           theme_classic() +
           labs(x = "Daily returns") +
           ggtitle(paste("Daily Returns for", ticker)) +
           scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(x)-.03, max(x)+0.03, .02),
                              labels = scales::percent)
         }) 
         
output$plot1 <-renderPlot({plt1()})
output$plot2 <-renderPlot({plt2()})
                      }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can handle Shiny for easier plots, but here with the parameters to use coming from estimation using the original data, I am really out of my league.

Comment: `daily_returns` should be `daily_returns()`? Otherwise you are just calling a reactive object which `pull` is not implemented for. What error do you get? It's kinda hard to reproduce this without data though.

Comment: The data is read in via the first part of the program using tidyquant. I fixed the daily_returns(), but still get the same error message.                                                 Warning: Error in : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
* You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
  63: <Anonymous>
Error : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
* You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.

Comment: tq_get is used to retrieve the data from Yahoo finance... So the program reads its own data.  It works just fine outside of Shiny. All problems begin inside Shiny. My first run using twice plot1 worked fine... it is something in plot 2 that is more complex, no doubts, that creates the issues, but cannot say what it is, sadly. Been at it for over one day almost non stop, but cannot fix it.

Comment: It's easier if the app can be run and debugged. Currently it's hard to do anything as it is not easily reproducible. The reactive error message is a good start but not clear where it shows up.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point. If you do not have the time, then you do not have the time. The end. But, if you load the program in your Rstudio, you will get all you need. The code is complete. So, it is not correct to say that it is "too hard to do anything". You have everything I have, as a matter of fact.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem stems from my use of the functions .. because I was able to get the plot of the histogram in there... Maybe in other 2-3 days I will find out what the issue is. Just maybe.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working solution. I have not attempted to use `req` and the like and leave that as an exercise for the reader. Why does OP's code fail?

OP is attempting to access reactive elements within functions for example in this line: `n()*log(sigma)+ sum((x()-mu)^2/sigma^2) - sum(csi0(alpha*(x()-mu)/sigma)) # negative log-likelihood`.

Here, the function `ll` attempts to access reactive object `x()` which is not compatible with the `shiny` reactivity philosophy. Similar ideas can be seen in functions `dsknorm` and `dnorms`. Converting these to reactive elements/objects fixes the issue. However, it is still necessary to use `req` and friends to "await" processes. Otherwise, you get the error "Missing Value where true/false is needed".

**NOTE** I have commented out some code from `plot2` that is not following `ggplot2` best practices. This is the code in question. We cannot add a `data.frame` object to a `ggplot2` object.

```
 scale_color_manual(name="distribution", values=c(skewed_normal="blue", normal="red")) +
      # daily_returns() %>%
      # ggplot(aes(x = daily.returns)) +geom_density()+
      # theme_classic() +
      # labs(x = "Daily returns") +
      # ggtitle(paste("Daily Returns for", ticker)) +
      # scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(x)-.03, max(x)+0.03, .02),
      #                    labels = scales::percent)
```

```
   # install.packages(c("tidyquant", "timetk", "moments", "stats4"))
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(moments)
library(stats4)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

stocknames <-c("AAPL","TSLA", "GME", "GOOG", "AMGN")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Fitting a skewed normal to stock returns"),
  
  sidebarLayout(position="left",
                sidebarPanel("Choose a stock from the list",
                             selectInput("tick", label = "", choices=stocknames)
                ),
                mainPanel("main panel", fluidRow(
                  splitLayout(style="border:1px solid silver:", cellWidths = c(400,400),
                              plotOutput("plot1"),
                              plotOutput("plot2")
                  )
                )
                )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  stockDatax <- reactive({
    tq_get(input$tick, get="stock.prices", from ="2015-01-01")
  })
  daily_returns <- reactive({
    stockDatax() %>%
      tq_transmute(select = adjusted,           # this specifies which column to select   
                   mutate_fun = periodReturn,   # This specifies what to do with that column
                   period = "daily")     
    
  })
  
  
  plt1 <- reactive({daily_returns() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = date, y = daily.returns )) +
      geom_line() +
      theme_classic() +
      labs(x = "Date", y = "daily returns") +
      ggtitle(paste("Daily Returns for ", input$tick)) +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years", date_labels = "%Y") +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.5,0.6,0.05),
                         labels = scales::percent) 
    
  })
  #  This is where the part related to plot 2 begins and where the error(s) lie...
  
  x<- reactive({pull(daily_returns(),2)})
  n <- reactive({length(x()) })
  # need this function for log-likelihood function immediately below.
  csi0 <-function(x){
    y<- log(2*dnorm(x))
    return(y)
  }
  
 est <- reactive({
   csi0 <-function(x){
     y<- log(2*dnorm(x))
     return(y)
   }
   ll<-function(mu, sigma, alpha){
     n()*log(sigma)+ sum((x()-mu)^2/sigma^2) -
       sum(csi0(alpha*(x()-mu)/sigma)) # negative log-likelihood
   }
   mle(minuslogl=ll, start=list(mu=0, sigma=1, alpha=-0.1))
  })
  # define likelihood function for skewed normal         
  
  # This uses mle to find the mle solutions numerically.             
  # est<-
  # summary(est)
  # extract the solutions to use them individually in what follows             
  m <- reactive({ unname(est()@coef[1]) })
  s <- reactive({ unname(est()@coef[2]) })
  a <- reactive({ unname(est()@coef[3]) })
  #
  # symbolic probability density function that uses the parameters just estimated above.             
  # dsknorm <- function(x){
  #   y <- 2/s*dnorm((x-m())/s())*pnorm(a()*(x-m())/s())
  #   return(y)
  # }
  # # doing the same for the normal distribution.             
  # MLE for normal distribution
  m1 <- reactive({mean(x()) })
  s1 <- reactive({sd(x()) })
 
  ylistnormdf <- reactive(
    print(sapply(grid_x(), function(x) dnorm(x, m1(), s1())))
  )
  
  ylistskdf <- reactive(
    print(sapply(grid_x(),
                 function(x) 2/s()*dnorm((x-m())/s())*pnorm(a()*(x-m())/s()) ))
  )
  
  
  grid_x <- reactive({ seq(min(x())-.03, max(x())+0.03, .005) })
  # ylistskdf <-reactive({sapply(grid_x(), dsknorm)})
  # ylistnormdf <-reactive({sapply(grid_x(), dnorms)})
  # create a dataframe to use for plotting
  dataToPlot <- reactive({data.frame(grid_x(), ylistnormdf(), ylistskdf()) })
  plt2 <- reactive({ggplot(data=dataToPlot(), aes(x=grid_x())) +
      geom_line(aes(y=ylistskdf(),colour="skewed_normal")) +
      geom_line(aes(y=ylistnormdf(),colour="normal")) +
      scale_color_manual(name="distribution", values=c(skewed_normal="blue", normal="red")) 
      # daily_returns() %>%
      # ggplot(aes(x = daily.returns)) +geom_density()+
      # theme_classic() +
      # labs(x = "Daily returns") +
      # ggtitle(paste("Daily Returns for", ticker)) +
      # scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(x)-.03, max(x)+0.03, .02),
      #                    labels = scales::percent)
  }) 
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({plt1()})
  output$plot2 <-renderPlot({plt2()})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. That is exactly what it looks like in a non Shiny document. I will make sure to understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You can accept this answer if it solves the issue @Maurice